# InternalError: Cannot dlopen all CUDA libraries

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am trying to run the Python code of [this](https://www.kaggle.com/madz2000/nlp-using-glove-embeddings-99-87-accuracy/notebook) Kaggle Jupyter Notebook and encounter following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-be0fb0b18f3a> in <module>
      1 #Defining Neural Network
----> 2 model = Sequential()
      3 #Non-trainable embeddidng layer
      4 model.add(Embedding(max_features, output_dim=embed_size, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=maxlen, trainable=False))
      5 #LSTM

c:\users\kim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    528     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    529     try:
--> 530       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    531     finally:
    532       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

c:\users\kim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py in __init__(self, layers, name)
    105     """
    106     # Skip the init in FunctionalModel since model doesn't have input/output yet
--> 107     super(functional.Functional, self).__init__(  # pylint: disable=bad-super-call
    108         name=name, autocast=False)
    109     base_layer.keras_api_gauge.get_cell('Sequential').set(True)

c:\users\kim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    528     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    529     try:
--> 530       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    531     finally:
    532       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

c:\users\kim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    287     self._steps_per_execution = None
    288 
--> 289     self._init_batch_counters()
    290     self._base_model_initialized = True
    291 

c:\users\kim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    528     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    529     try:
--> 530       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    531     finally:
    532       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

c:\users\kim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _init_batch_counters(self)
    295     # `evaluate`, and `predict`.
    296     agg = tf.VariableAggregation.ONLY_FIRST_REPLICA
--> 297     self._train_counter = tf.Variable(0, dtype='int64', aggregation=agg)
    298     self._test_counter = tf.Variable(0, dtype='int64', aggregation=agg)
    299     self._predict_counter = tf.Variable(

c:\users\kim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py in __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    266       return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)
    267     elif cls is Variable:
--> 268       return cls._variable_v2_call(*args, **kwargs)
    269     else:
    270       return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)

c:\users\kim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py in _variable_v2_call(cls, initial_value, trainable, validate_shape, caching_device, name, variable_def, dtype, import_scope, constraint, synchronization, aggregation, shape)
    248     if aggregation is None:
    249       aggregation = VariableAggregation.NONE
--> 250     return previous_getter(
    251         initial_value=initial_value,
    252         trainable=trainable,

c:\users\kim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py in <lambda>(**kws)
    241                         shape=None):
    242     """Call on Variable class. Useful to force the signature."""
--> 243     previous_getter = lambda **kws: default_variable_creator_v2(None, **kws)
    244     for _, getter in ops.get_default_graph()._variable_creator_stack:  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    245       previous_getter = _make_getter(getter, previous_getter)

c:\users\kim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variable_scope.py in default_variable_creator_v2(next_creator, **kwargs)
   2660   shape = kwargs.get("shape", None)
   2661 
-> 2662   return resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable(
   2663       initial_value=initial_value,
   2664       trainable=trainable,

c:\users\kim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py in __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    268       return cls._variable_v2_call(*args, **kwargs)
    269     else:
--> 270       return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    271 
    272 

c:\users\kim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py in __init__(self, initial_value, trainable, collections, validate_shape, caching_device, name, dtype, variable_def, import_scope, constraint, distribute_strategy, synchronization, aggregation, shape)
   1600       self._init_from_proto(variable_def, import_scope=import_scope)
   1601     else:
-> 1602       self._init_from_args(
   1603           initial_value=initial_value,
   1604           trainable=trainable,

c:\users\kim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\resource_variable_ops.py in _init_from_args(self, initial_value, trainable, collections, caching_device, name, dtype, constraint, synchronization, aggregation, distribute_strategy, shape)
   1743               self._update_uid = initial_value.checkpoint_position.restore_uid
   1744               initial_value = initial_value.wrapped_value
-> 1745             initial_value = ops.convert_to_tensor(initial_value,
   1746                                                   name="initial_value",
   1747                                                   dtype=dtype)

c:\users\kim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\profiler\trace.py in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    161         with Trace(trace_name, **trace_kwargs):
    162           return func(*args, **kwargs)
--> 163       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    164 
    165     return wrapped

c:\users\kim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, dtype_hint, ctx, accepted_result_types)
   1564 
   1565     if ret is None:
-> 1566       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
   1567 
   1568     if ret is NotImplemented:

c:\users\kim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_conversion_registry.py in _default_conversion_function(***failed resolving arguments***)
     50 def _default_conversion_function(value, dtype, name, as_ref):
     51   del as_ref  # Unused.
---> 52   return constant_op.constant(value, dtype, name=name)
     53 
     54 

c:\users\kim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    269     ValueError: if called on a symbolic tensor.
    270   """
--> 271   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
    272                         allow_broadcast=True)
    273 

c:\users\kim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    281       with trace.Trace("tf.constant"):
    282         return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
--> 283     return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    284 
    285   g = ops.get_default_graph()

c:\users\kim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    306 def _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape):
    307   """Creates a constant on the current device."""
--> 308   t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    309   if shape is None:
    310     return t

c:\users\kim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    103     except AttributeError:
    104       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
--> 105   ctx.ensure_initialized()
    106   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
    107 

c:\users\kim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py in ensure_initialized(self)
    534       opts = pywrap_tfe.TFE_NewContextOptions()
    535       try:
--> 536         config_str = self.config.SerializeToString()
    537         pywrap_tfe.TFE_ContextOptionsSetConfig(opts, config_str)
    538         if self._device_policy is not None:

c:\users\kim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py in config(self)
    962     """Return the ConfigProto with all runtime deltas applied."""
    963     # Ensure physical devices have been discovered and config has been imported
--> 964     self._initialize_physical_devices()
    965 
    966     config = config_pb2.ConfigProto()

c:\users\kim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py in _initialize_physical_devices(self, reinitialize)
   1291         return
   1292 
-> 1293       devs = pywrap_tfe.TF_ListPhysicalDevices()
   1294       self._physical_devices = [
   1295           PhysicalDevice(name=d.decode(), device_type=d.decode().split(":")[1])

InternalError: Cannot dlopen all CUDA libraries.
```

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I tried a few things and after installing tensorflow-gpu it worked. Maybe it can help someone else with this problem as well:

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```